# BASH - Splitting string at special occurence of character (underscore), depending on total number of underscores in string

Tags: string, bash, split, special-characters

I have a data frame with several columns and lines where one column contains different strings, each string being composed of a different number of underscores. I want to split each string in half, depending thus on the number of occurrences.

Example:

```
               ID_1                    ID_2     haplotypeID    ...
            A_B_A_B                 A_B_A_B         hap.1.1    ...
        A_B_C_A_B_C             A_B_C_A_B_C         hap.1.2    ...
    A_B_C_D_A_B_C_D         A_B_C_D_A_B_C_D         hap.2.1    ...
A_B_C_D_E_A_B_C_D_E     A_B_C_D_E_A_B_C_D_E         hap.2.1    ...
                ...                     ...             ...    ...
```

The output would be:

```
           ID_1             ID_2      haplotypeID    ...
            A_B              A_B          hap.1.1    ...
          A_B_C            A_B_C          hap.1.2    ...
        A_B_C_D          A_B_C_D          hap.2.1    ...
      A_B_C_D_E        A_B_C_D_E          hap.2.1    ...
            ...              ...              ...    ...
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, is it always going to be of the form `somestring_thatsamestring`? Will there be instances of `A_B_C_D` or only `A_B_A_B` in the input?

Comment: The input will always be symmetrical, meaning that in one string the instance will occur twice separated by an underscore in the form something_thatsamestring. A_B_A_B appears, but not A_B_C_D.

Comment: Try `sed -r 's/(^| )([^ ]*)_\2/\1\2/g' input.txt | column -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` for this:

```
$ cat input.txt
               ID_1                    ID_2     haplotypeID    ...
            A_B_A_B                 A_B_A_B         hap.1.1    ...
        A_B_D_A_B_D             A_B_C_A_B_C         hap.1.2    ...
    A_B_C_D_A_B_C_D         A_B_C_D_A_B_C_D         hap.2.1    ...
A_B_C_D_E_A_B_C_D_E     A_B_C_D_E_A_B_C_D_E         hap.2.1    ...
                ...                     ...             ...    ...

$ sed -r 's/(^| )([^ ]*)_\2/\1\2/g' input.txt | column -t
ID_1       ID_2       haplotypeID  ...
A_B        A_B        hap.1.1      ...
A_B_D      A_B_C      hap.1.2      ...
A_B_C_D    A_B_C_D    hap.2.1      ...
A_B_C_D_E  A_B_C_D_E  hap.2.1      ...
...        ...        ...          ...
```

OR

```
$ sed -r 's/(^| )( *)\2([^ ]*)_\3/\1\2\3/g' inp
               ID_1                    ID_2     haplotypeID    ...
      A_B         A_B         hap.1.1    ...
    A_B_D       A_B_C         hap.1.2    ...
  A_B_C_D     A_B_C_D         hap.2.1    ...
A_B_C_D_E   A_B_C_D_E         hap.2.1    ...
            ...                     ...             ...    ...
```

Logic:
Replace (string)_(repeat of same string) by (string)
In `sed` (& most other regex based tools), `\1`/`\2`/`\3` etc. refer to the backreferences of the previous matches.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, this worked perfectly!